# onclick of the close icon , close the corresponding minimized dialog from the container

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I am using jquery-ui dialog , now when i minimize the dialogs the dialog gets minimized into the container which is at the left. 
My problem is when i close the dialog , i also want to close it from the minimized container too.

My dialog's have id of dialog_1,dialog_2,dialog_3... and the minimized dialogs will have id of 1_minimized,2_minimized...

i tried this to the close click function,

```
$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').click(function(){
$( '#' + dialog_id + '_minimized').hide();
});
```

For the close and restore button

```
$('#dialog_window_minimized_container').append(
            '<div class="dialog_window_minimized ui-widget ui-resizable ui-state-    default ui-corner-all" id="' + 
            dialog_id + '_minimized">' + this.uiDialogTitlebar.find('.ui-dialog-title').text() + '<span class="ui-min-icon ui-icon ui-icon-newwin"/>  <span class="ui-minimized-close ui-icon ui-icon-close"/></div>');
```

But it closes all the below child dialogs too. For example if i have 10 dialogs and if i click the close of the 5th dialog, all the below 6,7,8..10 also closes.

How can i actually restrict it to close only the corresponding minimized dialog??

Cheers

Comment: IDs shouldn't be only a number or beginning with a number. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

Comment: ok. will keep that in mind.Does it got to go anything with this functionality or it's just the basic knowledge yo giving me.?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like `$('#'+dialog_id+'_minimized').hide();`

Because if you give space it will treat like `$('# 1 _minimized').`

But your selector is `$('#1_minimized')`

Comment: but that's not my issue, the $('selector').hide(); is functioning wel, but at the same time it's hiding all it's descendants also , i want to close only that particular 1_minimized , but 2_minimized, 3_minimized also gets closed.!

Comment: Ok. If you show your problem in jsfiddle that will help to inspect the issue.